# mercurial push subset of directories to secondary remote site

Tags: mercurial, push

I'm considering using Mercurial in our small office.  We've got a development server, a staging server and a live server.  The live server contains our web site, the staging server contains our web site and additionally some intranet directories that should not be pushed to the live server.

In setting up Mercurial - is there any way to be able to push the entire repository to the staging server: our public site as well as the intranet directories, but, when pushing to the live server only send those directories associated with the public site?

In other words - when pushing to staging, push everything. When pushing to live, exclude the directories for the intranet site?

-Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push and pull operations act on the entire repository only.  Some other options available are:

- use `hg archive -X` to build an archive file with a subset of the repo (tip only, no history)

or

- split your repo into multiple repos (ex: internal and external) that are *subrepos* of a larger repo.  Have the outer repo on the dev and staging machine, and push only the external repo to production.

Comment: thanks - actually we ended up extracting the sections of the site that should not be live and putting them in a separate subdomain - so they're now separate repositories.